# Add additional data to template of FOS User Bundle

Tags: fosuserbundle, symfony-forms, symfony

How can I add additional data to the templates of the FOS User Bundle?
I know how to customize the form fields and how to react to the FOS User Bundle events to hook into the form evaluation process - but I don't get how to pass more arguments to the templates then the pure forms.

A.e. I need to pass a variable into the registration template.

Any help is very welcome.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can override any bundle easily in your project to change/add anything you need on entities, controllers, forms and templates... See documentation about that:

- http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/override.html
- http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_templates.html
- http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_controllers.html
- http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_forms.html